# Singleton spring bean is being created more than once

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have a singleton spring bean named gameContext, my spring bean definition;

```
    <bean name="gameContext" scope="singleton"
      class="tr.com.hevi.game.numblock.core.context.GameContext"/>
```

I also use this class for session listening, here is my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        tr.com.hevi.game.numblock.core.context.GameContext
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

The problem is that gameContext is being created twice. one; at the very beginning before the spring context is being loaded, and the second; within the spring context.

I am sure that I do not component-scan more than once.

I understand the reason behind but don't know how to tackle the problem. One possible solution should be adding the listener within the spring context not web.xml, or there might be a proxy object solution.

Answer (score 3):

In your problem, there are 2 objects for spring because you are configuring the listener twice

1. The first is in the web.xml (outside the spring context)
2. Within the spring context as a bean.

The easiest way to have only 1 instance is if you are using the Servlet 3.0 specification. Here the `ServletContext` has a addListener() method make use of the same. Do something like the below:

```
@Component
public class MyCustomListener implements javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener, ApplicationContextAware {

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if (applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
            ((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext).getServletContext().addListener(this);
        } else {
            //Either throw an exception or fail gracefully, up to you
            throw new RuntimeException("Must be inside a web application context");
        }
    }           
}
```

The above approach will cause you to create only 1 object of the listener, and have the same object registered as a Servlet listener and spring bean.